# Model value not set from controller in Angular UI Tree

Tags: angularjs

I am using angular UI Tree.

In this i have applied one date picker and one text field.

Now while setting model value from Controller function, It is not visible to the Front View.However i can see the value in Console.

Here is my code.

```
$scope.startFromTasks[data.slider.context.id.split("_")[1]] = moment(data.from*1000).toDate('MM-dd-yyyy');
    $scope.startFromTasksModel[data.slider.context.id.split("_")[1]] = moment(data.from*1000).format('MM/DD/YYYY');

    $scope.startToTasks[data.slider.context.id.split("_")[1]] = moment(data.to*1000).toDate('MM-DD-YYYY');
    $scope.startToTasksModel[data.slider.context.id.split("_")[1]] = moment(data.to*1000).format('MM/DD/YYYY');

    var a = moment(moment(data.from*1000).format('MM/DD/YYYY'));
    var b = moment(moment(data.to*1000).format('MM/DD/YYYY'));

    $scope.setToDaysTasks[data.slider.context.id.split("_")[1]] = moment.duration(b.diff(a)).asDays();
    $("#setsliderDaysTasks_"+data.slider.context.id.split("_")[1]).value = 10;
    $scope.$apply();
```

Here `$scope.startFromTasks, $scope.setToDaysTasks` are my model.

Answer (score 0):

It may be your digest cycle is busy . you can check for the digest cycle

```
$scope.putAsafeApply = function(fn) {
var status = this.$root.$$phase;
if(status == '$apply' || status == '$digest') {
 if(fn && (typeof(fn) === 'function')) {
 fn();
 }
 } else {
this.$apply(fn);
}
};
```

wrap your code within the putAsafeApply

```
$scope.putAsafeApply(function() {
$scope.startFromTasks[data.slider.context.id.split("_")[1]] = moment(data.from*1000).toDate('MM-dd-yyyy');
    $scope.startFromTasksModel[data.slider.context.id.split("_")[1]] = moment(data.from*1000).format('MM/DD/YYYY');

    $scope.startToTasks[data.slider.context.id.split("_")[1]] = moment(data.to*1000).toDate('MM-DD-YYYY');
    $scope.startToTasksModel[data.slider.context.id.split("_")[1]] = moment(data.to*1000).format('MM/DD/YYYY');

    var a = moment(moment(data.from*1000).format('MM/DD/YYYY'));
    var b = moment(moment(data.to*1000).format('MM/DD/YYYY'));

    $scope.setToDaysTasks[data.slider.context.id.split("_")[1]] = moment.duration(b.diff(a)).asDays();

});
```

You can look here [enter link description here](http://javacourseblog.blogspot.in/2014/06/angularjs-apply-digest-in-detail-with.html)

Comment: Right now my code is inside one function. So how can i do this?